# Ball Mechanics - Is this the best approach?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

Good day,

I'd like to program a constantly moving ball (`object3`) being passed between two stationary objects (`object1`, `object2`), with the ability to set the max height `Y` of the pass trajectory dynamically.

[image: Object3 bounces between Object1 and Object2 automatically, despite a variable height factor.]

What would you argue is the best way to program the ball physics for this concept?

I've looked at using `addForce` on a default sphere w/ a rigidbody. It seems like there should be an equation that expresses the trajectory of a pass of `object3` from `object1`'s x to `object2`'s x... at a known, given `speed`, with a known, set `mass`, and a known gravity environment.

However, currently I have a `Vector3.Lerp` interpolating the ball between the two objects on each `FixedUpdate()` with `t` expressed as:

```
`(Mathf.Sin(speed * Time.time) + 1.0f) / 2.0f;`
```

It works and all, but with this approach, it seems there's no clear way to add `height` to the trajectory of the ball path. I've considered adding the `height` to the `Y` value in `object2` until the ball is half way there, and then setting it back to the original `Y` position... but it just feels wrong! Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a visual off what you are trying to achieve .. sure it's me but currently I can't imagine what exactly your goal is. As I understand you want the ball move forth and back between the two given objects .. but where and how comes the `height` into play?

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for writing.  Just added an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey so if I understand you correctly currently you are doing

```c#
privte void FixedUpdate()
{
    var factor = (Mathf.Sin(speed * Time.time) + 1.0f) / 2.0f;
    object1.MovePosition(Vector3.Lerp(object2.position, object3.position, factor));
}
```

which moves the ball pingpong between `object1` and `object2` position but only planar.

**Assuming for now the objects will only be moving within the XZ plane and never have different Y position** in order to rather get a curve with height you could treat the separatly: 
 - Interpolate between both positions as before
 - Separately calculate the Y position with sinus or any other mathematical curve function - for realistic physics probably rather a parabola actually

Could look somhow like

```c#
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody object1;
    public Transform object2;
    public Transform object3;

    // adjust in the Inspector
    public float speed = 1;
    public float Amplitude = 0;

    // Just for debug
    [Range(0, 1)] [SerializeField] private float linearFactor;
    [SerializeField] private float yPosition;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // This always returns a value between 0 and 1 
        // and linearly pingpongs forth and back
        linearFactor = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, 1);
        // * Mathf.PI => gives now a value 0 - PI
        // so sinus returns correctly 0 - 1 (no need for +1 and /2 anymore)
        // then simply multiply by the desired amplitude
        var sinus = Mathf.Sin(linearFactor * Mathf.PI);
        yPosition = sinus * Amplitude;

        // As before interpolate between the positions
        // later we will ignore/replace the Y component
        var position = Vector3.Lerp(object2.position, object3.position, linearFactor);

        object1.MovePosition(new Vector3(position.x, yPosition, position.z));
    }
}
```

[image]

---

You could optionally also try and add some dumping in the Y direction in order to make the vertical movement more realistic (slow down when reaching the peak). I tried a bit using inverted `SmoothStep` like

```c#
// just for debug
[Range(0, 1)] [SerializeField] private float dampedSinusFactor;
[Range(0, 1)] [SerializeField] private float linearFactor;
[SerializeField] private float yPosition;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Use two different factros:
    // - a linear one for movement in XZ
    // - a smoothed one for movement in Y (in order to slow down when reaching the peak ;) )
    linearFactor = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, 1);
    dampedSinusFactor = InvertSmoothStep(linearFactor);

    // * Mathf.PI => gives now a value 0 - PI
    // so sinus returns correctly 0 - 1 ()
    // then simply multiply by the desired amplitude
    var sinus = Mathf.Sin(dampedSinusFactor * Mathf.PI);
    yPosition = sinus * Amplitude;

    // later we will ignore/replace the Y component
    var position = Vector3.Lerp(object2.position, object3.position, linearFactor);

    object1.position = new Vector3(position.x, yPosition, position.z);
}

// source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34576808/7111561
private float InvertSmoothStep(float x)
{
    return x + (x - (x * x * (3.0f - 2.0f * x)));
}
```

However for slow movements this looks a bit strange yet. But you can come up with any other maths curve that results in the expected behavior for `x=[0,1]` ;)

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm going to try to implement this now.

Comment: Glad to help :) btw if you want this to be more like physics you would probably use a parabola instead of sinus ;)

Comment: Ok I will try that first then! Yeah I definitely want it to represent a ball going between two objects in a physical world.